# What is meant by id's and labels in keras data generator?

Tags: keras

[https://stanford.edu/~shervine/blog/keras-how-to-generate-data-on-the-fly](https://stanford.edu/%7Eshervine/blog/keras-how-to-generate-data-on-the-fly)

The like above is the documentation regarding the custom keras data generator.

I have doubt in the "NOTATION" heading in the above link which says the following:-

Before getting started, let's go through a few organizational tips that are particularly useful when dealing with large datasets.

Let ID be the Python string that identifies a given sample of the dataset. A good way to keep track of samples and their labels is to adopt the following framework:

```
1. Create a dictionary called partition where you gather:
       a) in partition['train'] a list of training IDs
       b) in partition['validation'] a list of validation IDs

2. Create a dictionary called labels where for each ID of the dataset, the associated label is given by labels[ID]
```

For example, let's say that our training set contains id-1, id-2 and id-3 with respective labels 0, 1 and 2, with a validation set containing id-4 with label 1. In that case, the Python variables partition and labels look like

```
      >>> partition
      {'train': ['id-1', 'id-2', 'id-3'], 'validation': ['id-4']}
```

and

```
      >>> labels
      {'id-1': 0, 'id-2': 1, 'id-3': 2, 'id-4': 1}
```

I'm really not able to understand what does labels and id's mean.

For example:- Say, I have a data frame, where there are 1000 columns. Each row corresponds to id's i.e., each ID meant to be just a "DATA POINT".

OR

Say, I have multiple data frame. Each data frame represents different id's?

It seems labels meant not to be the number of class-variable.

I would like to have a clear understanding regarding id's and labels WITH SOME EXAMPLES.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mentioned article provides a good practice to better organize your data between training and validation. To do so, it's relevant to store line indexes from your dataframe (named IDs here) and corresponding target values (named label here) in an independent object so that in case of transformation on the input, you don't lose track of things.

Here is a basic example using a train/test split

````
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

df = pd.DataFrame([[0.1, 1, 'label_a'], [0.2, 2, 'label_a'], [0.3, 3, 'label_a'], [0.4, 4, 'label_b']], columns=['feature_a', 'feature_b', 'target'])

# df.index.tolist() results in [0, 1, 2, 3] (4 rows)

partitions = dict()
labels = dict()

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(df[['feature_a', 'feature_b']], df['target'], test_size=0.25, random_state=42)

partitions['train'] = X_train.index.tolist()
partitions['validation'] = X_test.index.tolist()

# partitions['train'] results in [3, 0, 2]
# partitions['validation'] results in [1]

labels = df['target'].to_dict()

# labels is {0: 'label_a', 1: 'label_a', 2: 'label_a', 3: 'label_b'}```
````